# How do I burp a 2006 Subaru Forester?

Tags: subaru, cooling-system, forester

2006 Subaru Forester cooling system issue. Fans next to radiator work when A/C is turned on. No heat coming from Heaters . No leaks. A/C recently re-gassed. Alerted to the problem when radiator boiled over suddenly recently but refilled with coolant since then. When radiator boiled over the water that sprayed out all over engine was rusty orange color and smelt quite toxic. Lots of good info on this site including 'burping' the air out from the cooling system . Just not quite sure how to o that ....Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You may be burping up the wrong tree. Consider that you may have a blown head gasket. You can do a quick / cheap test for hydrocarbons or exhaust gases in your coolant by picking up a head gasket test kit. If you get positive results, best to confirm with a mechanic.

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The AC regassing has absolutely nothing to do with your radiator, AC and engine cooling are completely different systems.

I think you are on the wrong track looking at burping the system, you describe rust colored smelly water in the overflow, which means you definitely have corrosion and likely a block in your cooling system which is restricting flow. A flush may be enough to fix it but you may need a new radiator and possibly some hoses.